# How work with soap in Spring boot like an object?

Tags: java, xml, soap

I got soap project, thats works with xsd file. But I no idea how to work with soap.
How i can work with xsd file like an object?
What I need, get some data from database, set values to object, map to xsd file and sent to request with xsd file body
XSD:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
              xmlns:xro="http://x-road.eu/xsd/xroad.xsd"
              xmlns:iden="http://xroad.eu/xsd/identifiers"
              xmlns:erec="http://testrecord_service.x-road.ee/testrecord">

<soapenv:Header>
    <xro:protocolVersion>4.0</xro:protocolVersion>
    <xro:issue>123</xro:issue>
    <xro:id>123</xro:id>
    <xro:userId>123</xro:userId>

    <xro:service iden:objectType="SERVICE">
        <iden:xRoadInstance>central-server</iden:xRoadInstance>
        <iden:memberClass>test</iden:memberClass>
        <iden:memberCode>test coed</iden:memberCode>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <iden:subsystemCode>test-service</iden:subsystemCode>
        <iden:serviceCode>testrecord</iden:serviceCode>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <iden:serviceVersion>v1</iden:serviceVersion>
    </xro:service>

    <xro:client iden:objectType="SUBSYSTEM">
        <iden:xRoadInstance>test-server</iden:xRoadInstance>
        <iden:memberClass>test</iden:memberClass>
        <iden:memberCode>testcode</iden:memberCode>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <iden:subsystemCode>test-service</iden:subsystemCode>
    </xro:client>

</soapenv:Header>

<soapenv:Body>
    <erec:Authentication>
        <erec:companyIdentifier>cc93a8c3-465d-4813-a442-
            69539692e0a1</erec:companyIdentifier>
        <erec:pin>12345</erec:pin>
    </erec:Authentication>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Are you using a SOAP framework or rolling your own? It looks like you are asking for an entire SOAP solution, which no one here really wants to write for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh .. I see xroad :). use maven-jaxb2-plugin to generate pojo models from xsd.  Grab data from database, map it to pojo generated previously and pass it to the ws client

Beware that some xsd schemas of xroad are insufficient.

You'd better to hide authentication details from your question.

Comment: udp: Cant generate pojo, cause: Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException (at /soapenv:Envelope): faultCode=INVALID_WSDL: Expected element '{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/}definitions'.
 I guess it is`not xsd or wsdl format?

Comment: Yes, i was wrong a bit. You might have to refer to vendor to get a correct wsdl.

Comment: 1 .Is the wsdl from the service provider mandatory?                                                             2. Can work without wsdl or make own wsdl?